# Use array to show elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a problem that I can't figure out and was wondering if you good people could help out? I'm building a filter system that uses data options on the tags.

> The nav elements add to an array when pressed and take that option out
>   of the array when pressed again.

You may notice that the first set allows for combination and the date range doesn't. This is intentional. My problem lies with asking the script to show the elements in the #container that match the data tag when pressed - I want to show the li elements within #container that match the data-season="" or the data-date="".

in the seasons script this is my problematic piece of script....

```
if (typeof $("#container li").data('season' == showseason ) )
{
    $(this).show();
}
```

I've tried various ways but I'm now just going in loops getting more confused with each attempt. HELP :)

[Jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/daviemurphy/b2eh2w07/3/)

Comment: I think you should really have researched what [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) does, rather than just used it because it (presumably) 'sounded right'. Also, the equality operator *inside of* the [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method means you're looking for a `data-true`/`data-false` (I think) variable, not assessing the returned attribute-string. Please: check the documentation when something doesn't work. Incidentally, when posting a problem, post a *minimal* demo, in order to get help.

Comment: I've now shortened it as much as possible http://jsfiddle.net/daviemurphy/b2eh2w07/10/

Answer (score 1):

You should change that `if` statement. remove the `typeof` keyword, and compare the `data` value.

```
    if ($("#container li").data('season') == showseason )
    {  
         // do something here
    }
```

Or better yet, iterate through each of the `li` within `#container` and get the `data-season` value.

```
$("#container li").each(function(){
  var season = $(this).data("season");

  if(season == showseason) 
     $(this).show();
  else
     $(this).hide();
});
```

Please refer to the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b2eh2w07/11/

Comment: this will be faster than $(this)

Comment: Hi, cheers for the help but I'm not getting any results within the #container still. Is my selector wrong perhaps?

Comment: if ($("#container li").data('season') == showseason )
  {
         $("#container li[data-season=]" + showseason).show();
  }

Something like this, albeit the [data-season=] + showseason isn't quite right?

Comment: ok that works but only on the first button (spring). I really wanted to only show the .li's within #container if the data-season on the button matches that of the data-season on the li. So, when you hit the button that has data-season="spring" only the #container li[data-season="spring"] elements show?

Comment: @user3648221 I've updated my answer, with an updated version of your fiddle.

Comment: You can simplify (and maybe even speed up) your code by using `$("#container li").hide();` and `$("#container li[data-season='" + showseason + "']").show();`

Comment: @Regent Even better, `$("#container li").hide().filter("[data-season='" + showseason + "']").show();`

Comment: @DJDavid98 yeah, that's for sure :)

Comment: Both work well Kyle and Regent. Would there be any way to amend that though to check if the data exists somewhere in the 'seasonfilter' and 'datefilter' arrays that I'm setting earlier in the script? this would allow me to combine filter results with data-season and also data-date and also when a 'button' is in an unselected state its data- will be eliminated from either of the two 'global' arrays and hide its results in the #container?

Comment: So for example...

Unselected... 1. click season button - add data add array 'seasonfilter' - I'm already doing this! 2. Set state of button - I'm already doing this! 3. check the 'seasonfilter and 'datefilter' arrays 4. show any $(#container li) elements only if they have data within the ‘seasonfilter' and 'datefilter' arrays?

Comment: Selected... 1. click season li.selected - remove data in array 'seasonfilter' - I'm already doing this! 2. Reset state of button - I'm already doing this! 3. check the 'seasonfilter and 'datefilter' arrays 4. show any $(#container li) elements only if they have data within the ‘seasonfilter' and 'datefilter' arrays?

Comment: @user3648221 take a look at [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Regent3000/b2eh2w07/18/). And please use '@username' in your comments to notice user that there is new comment for him

Comment: @Regent cheers for keeping me right and another solution option :) Only problem is the js code won't now allow the user to chose more than one option on the seasons. that was the difference between the two menu types - one allowed for multiple 'select' the other only one at a time. Half way there though :)

Comment: @user3648221 well, yes, I designed it for single option. If you need multiple options, you can use [this code](http://jsfiddle.net/Regent3000/b2eh2w07/20/)

Comment: @Regent You sir, are a true gent and an absolute star. Thank You! Spasiba!